# Broken links when deploying Clojure webapps to Jetty with relative links and non-root context path

Tags: clojure, jetty, compojure, ring, enlive

I've been experimenting with writing webapps in Clojure, and it's been pretty easy until now. I followed Chas Emerick's excellent screencast [starting clojure](http://cemerick.com/2012/05/02/starting-clojure/) and got an url shortener up and running pretty quickly. Next I wanted to be able to deploy it, and that's when the trouble started.

When I run it in development or deploy it to Jetty as the root webapp, everything is fine, but when I deploy it with a context path, it doesn't. Or, rather, it almost works. All my Compojure routes still work, but `FORM` action links in HTML files are broken and give me 404's.

This is the Compojure route setup:

```
  (defroutes app*
    (rt/resources "/")
    (GET "/" request (homepage request))
    (POST "/shorten" request
          (let [id (shorten (-> request :params :url))]
            (response/redirect "/")))
    (GET "/:id" [id] (redirect id)))

  (def app (compojure.handler/site app*))
```

And here is the HTML for the homepage template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="shorten">
        <input type="text" name="url" />
        <input type="submit" value="Shorten!" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is the `action="shorten"`URL. When deployed to Jetty with a context path of `/example` everything work fine, until I trigger the form submit. Then Jetty complains that it can't find `localhost:8080/shorten` which means (I think) that it's not being treated as a relative path, but an absolute one.

So, my question is: how to fix this? I guess I could just specify the full path in the action link, but that would be inflexible and make it harder to run the servlet in development. Is there a way to configure my way out of this? Or some magic URL prefix (like `~/` in Razor) that will just do the right thing?

Comment: Are you accessing that form from /example? Since it's a relative path in your action, your browser ought to be prepending it with your current URI. Maybe load up Firebug or some HTTP inspector and see if you're getting a redirect.

Comment: Yes, I'm accessing it from /example ... and the css file in the <HEAD> is being served correctly (via a 304 redirect) - but the <FORM> action is not.

Comment: When you click submit, do you see any redirects for page requests? ...like a 301 from /example/shorten to /shorten?

Comment: No, triggering the FORM action does not cause a redirect - just a plain GET to /shorten

Comment: It's the trailing slash. If you go to /example/ then the form will post to /example/shorten. Without the trailing slash, the browser views 'example' as a file at / and the form as wanting 'shorten' instead of 'example'. I don't know how to fix it in your situation, though. In my previous experience I've set redirects for trailing slashes and, in fact, when serving a request for a literal directory  Apache will send those redirects by default.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem. Change the line:

```
(POST "/shorten" request
```

to

```
(POST "shorten" request
```

and it should work (well, it did for me)